# Adding trailing zeros to rows of data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'd like to add trailing zeros to a data set however there is a `WHERE` clause involved. In a `DOB` field I have a date of `1971` and I'd like to add `0000` to make the length equal 8 characters. Sometimes there is `197108` which then I'd need to only add two `00`. The fields that are `null` are ok. Any ideas?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's a training zero?

Comment: u mean **trailing** zeroes?

Comment: I'm sorry.. trailing zeros :-)

Comment: No examples seem to be working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update table
    set Dob = CONCAT(TRIM(Dob), '0')
  where LEN(TRIM(Dob)) < 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add trailing zeros by doing:

```
select left(col+space(8), 8)
```

However, you probably shouldn't be storing date in a character field.

Answer (score 0):

Try REPLICATE function.

```
REPLICATE('0',8-LEN(CAST(DOB AS NVARCHAR))) + CAST(DOB AS NVARCHAR)
```

Edit: Try this

```
select REPLICATE('0',8-LEN('1985')) + '1985'
```

Comment: TRIM not recognized as a built in fi=unction in MS SQL 2008??

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(dob as nvarchar) + replicate('0',(8)-len(cast(dob as nvarchar)))
from table_name
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15750)

Comment: this worked but just selected the data didn't update the data

Comment: `update table_name
set dob = cast(dob as nvarchar) + replicate('0',(8)-len(cast(dob as nvarchar)))`